# Cpanel send delivered mail back to the mail queue to be delivered to the specific email address again

Tags: linux, cpanel, whm, exim

Open to other options..

For a specific user(home/user/mail/domain.com/username) I need to resend the mail that have been already delivered. (Also mail from cur, tmp, new)

Also target mail from a specific past date to now.

Exim Mail queue is currently empty.

Answer (score 0):

No, It is not possible to forward that mails which are already delivered to your mailbox.